Why can I not use a straight import of a custom function in vue3? Results in "x is not a function" error
This drove me insane, and I figured out a workaround. But I want to understand why it does not work in a straight forward way.
Essentially, I have my main vue view, and a custom function I want to import.
support.js
export function hello(what){
    return what
}

view.vue
<script>
   import { hello } from "@/support.js"
   export default{...}
</script>
<template>
   <h1> {{ hello("world") }} </h1>
</template>

And this setup does not work, giving me the "_ctx.hello is not a function" error.
(I also tried using this.hello() )
What does work however is if I use the function indirectly, via methods. E.g.:
view.vue
<script>
   import { hello } from "@/support.js"
   export default{
   ...
      methods:{
         hello_local(what){
            return hello(what)
         }
      }
   }
</script>
<template>
   <h1> {{ hello_local("world") }} </h1>
</template>

Which then yields the expected results.
I am sure there is a very simple explanation for this, but it elludes me. Can anyone tell me why the direct use of the imported function does not work?

Did you try export default function hello(... in your js file?

Basically, a .vue file is not a plain .js file, but a "vue templating language" file. In order to run vue app in a browser, you firstly should compile it into regular JavaScript. To make it simpler for the compiler, you should follow "vue templating language" syntax rules. The example you provided shows some code that is not possible in regular HTML or JavaScript.
According to the message you got compiled JavaScript tries to call hello_local method from the internal _ctx object, but as you haven't followed the vue syntax rules, the function hello_local was not compiled to be in a _ctx object, resulting in the error.

It's simply not a part of the Vue instance. If you want to use it in the template, you have to add it to the methods. You can just assign it instead of calling it. methods: { hello }
Also, with new Vue 3 it is possible directly with setup:
https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup
<script setup>
  import { capitalize } from './helpers'
</script>

<template>
  <div>{{ capitalize('hello') }}</div>
</template>


That issue you’re experiencing is related to how Vue templates handle expressions and the scope in which they execute. In Vue.js, expressions inside templates are evaluated in the context of the component instance, meaning they have access to properties, data, and methods that are part of the component’s instance this.
But, they don’t directly have access to imported functions or variables that are not part of this context.
